# Can I read http response until certain substring?

Tags: http, curl

I'm using http GET for massive (the greatest of them 500 M) datatables. From those tables I only need data until substring "DATA=". Could it be possible to stop reading data when this substring has been received ?

Answer (score 1):

This command line writes the download to a file using tee until grep exits due to a match:

```
$ curl http://example.com/HUGE | tee keeper| grep -q "quit immediately once found"
```

If that found the substring:

```
$ echo $?
$ 0
```

If it didn't:

```
$ echo $?
$ 1
```

This command line works because grep -q is documented to:

```
   -q, --quiet, --silent
          Quiet; do not write anything to standard  output.   Exit  immediately  with
          zero status if any match is found, even if an error was detected.  Also see
          the -s or --no-messages option.
```

Comment: Thanks for yout answer, but maybe my question was badly formatted as I'm actually scraping web pages with scrapy and I need to know how to "tell scrapy" (for instance in http request headers) to read until certain substring . I doubt that it's not possible, but I was asked to figure out.

Comment: Then please update the question and add the relevant tags!